# std::future_error: No associated state

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, promise, future

I have a problem with C++ 11 future/promise.
The following code works fine:

```
string s = "not written";

void write(promise<void>&& writePromise)
{
    cout << "\nwrite()" << endl;
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
    s = "written";
    writePromise.set_value();
}

void read(future<void>&& readFut)
{
    cout << "read(), waiting..." << flush;
    readFut.wait();
    cout << "\ns: '" << s << "'" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    promise<void> writePromise;
    future<void> writeFuture = writePromise.get_future();

    thread tWrite(write, move(writePromise));
    thread tRead(read, move(writeFuture));
    
    tWrite.join();
    tRead.join();
}
```

But once I change main() to this:

```
int main()
{
    promise<void> writePromise;

    thread tWrite(write, move(writePromise));
    thread tRead(read, move(writePromise.get_future()));
    
    tWrite.join();
    tRead.join();
}
```

I get the error:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::future_error'
what():  std::future_error: No associated state
Aborted (core dumped)

This exception is supposed to be thrown if you call get_future() twice on the same promise.

But all I did was just passing writePromise.get_future() to a function, so I don;t see how I call it twice.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3):

You moved `writePromise` before generating future from it. This is because the thread takes ownership over the promise by value.

To fix it - first obtain future and only then forward the promise.

Answer (score 0):

My first oops is related with your move semantics approach

Once you writes `move(writePromise)` the promise access should be **avoided** because the local var has been "*transferred*" to the thread according my understanding

My main lesson with the `std::move` could be summarized as

> since now i pass my enclosed var ownership to the called symbol

So, any posterior reference it's usually marked as invalid

IHTH